# NavBar button's action is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My code:

```
-(void)loadView {
[super loadView];
self.informationButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.informationButton;
self.informationButton.target = self;
self.informationButton.action = @selector(showHelpInfo);
}

-(void)showHelpInfo {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" 
                                                message:@"Test" 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"cansel" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Then I clicking on my `informationButton` uialertview not shows. There is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UIButton is the thing that now dispatches actions and events because the UIBarButtonItem is merely a container for it at this point.  So, when you click that button, it's the UIButton that's intercepting the touch event.  Simply make a UIButton object that has the same action your UIBarButtonItem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *iButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    [iButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showHelpInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.informationButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:iButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.informationButton;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the target of the `UIButton` to be `showHelpInfo` selector...